# Proving monotonicity of the regulated integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**The problem:** Let $f$ and $g$ be regulated functions on a closed interval $I$, such that for all $x \in I$, $\ $ $f(x) \ge g(x)$. Let $a, b \in I$ such that $a<b$. How can one show that the regulated integral is monotonic, i.e. that

$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx \ge \int_a^b g(x)dx \quad ?
$$

**My attempt:** So far, I've got

$$
\int_a^b f(x)dx \ge \int_a^b g(x)dx  \iff \int_a^bf(x)-g(x)dx \ge 0 \quad \text{(by linearity)}
$$

and

$$
\int_a^b f(x)-g(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^bf_n(x)-g_n(x)dx
$$
where $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ are sequences of step functions which converge uniformly to $f$ and $g$, respectively. So the proof will be done if we can show
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^bf_n(x)-g_n(x)dx \ge 0.
$$

This will follow if we can show that, letting the partition of each step function $f_n-g_n \in (f_n-g_n)$ be denoted $a=x_0<x_1< \dots <x_n=b$, and letting $c_i$ be an arbitrary point in the open interval $(x_{i-1}, x_i)$, we have

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n (f_n(c_i)-g_n(c_i))(x_i-x_{i-1}) \ge 0.
$$

Now I'm stuck; how can we show the above inequality? I think we'd have to use the fact that $f-g$ is always nonnegative on $I$, but I can't figure out the technical details. Maybe this whole approach is not the best? Please help.

Comment: It is enough to prove that $\phi \geq 0 \Rightarrow \int_a^b \phi \geq 0$ and then apply with $\phi:= f-g$. 

Also, what is your definition of the integral ?

Comment: The definition is given by definitions 1.3.10 and 1.3.2 in the following link: http://exordio.qfb.umich.mx/archivos%20pdf%20de%20trabajo%20umsnh/aphilosofia/2007/chap1.pdf

Comment: This also is why I've been having trouble using the method you just described. To show $\phi \ge 0 \implies \int_a^b \phi \ge 0$ I would need to show that $\phi \ge 0 \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \phi_n \ge 0$ where $(\phi_n)$ is a sequence of step functions which uniformly converges to $\phi$. So, things boil down to the problem above.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done. Since $f\geq g$ and since $f_n-g_n\to f-g$ uniformly, there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_n\geq g_n$ for all $n\geq N$.  So $f_n(c_i)\geq g_n(c_i)$ for all such $n$, and thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (f_n(c_i)-g_n(c_i))(x_i-x_{i-1}) \ge 0 \qquad (n\geq N). $$
From this, it follows that
$$ \int_a^b f_n(x)\ dx \ge \int_a^b g_n(x)\ dx, $$
and therefore
$$ \int_a^bf(x)\ dx\geq\int_a^bg(x)\ dx. $$

Comment: Thanks, but how can we prove that there is some $N \in \textbf{N}$ such that $f_n \ge g_n$ for all $n \ge N$? For example, what's to stop all the approximating step functions from only approaching $f-g$ "from below," that is, if $f_n-g_n$ approaches $0$ but is always negative?

Comment: If so, just redefine $f_n$ and $g_n$ to be equal on such subintervals.